# Zooming on center of image in panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a panel which allows zooming and panning an image in winforms and .Net 3.5
I think that I am nearly there, but am running into trouble with the zoom functionality.

I am trying to zoom in on the centre of the image, but somehow am slightly off. I'm having a really bad time thinking about the geometry and would really appreciate some help to figure out where I am going wrong.

Here is the code:

```
public class ImageViewer : Panel
{
    public double ZoomFactor
    {
        get { return this.zoomFactor; }
        set
        {
            this.zoomFactor = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public Point Translation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The image to be displayed
    /// </summary>
    [Category("Appearance"), Description("The image to be displayed.")]
    public Image Image
    {
        get { return this.image; }
        set
        {
            this.image = value;
            this.ZoomExtents();
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private double initialScale;
    private double zoomFactor;
    private Image image;
    private Point startingPoint;

    /// <summary>
    /// Class constructor
    /// </summary>
    public ImageViewer()
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the Zoom to a value where the whole image is visible.
    /// </summary>
    public void ZoomExtents()
    {
        if (this.Image == null)
            return;

        this.initialScale = Math.Min((double)this.Width / this.Image.Width, (double)this.Height / this.Image.Height);

        this.Invalidate();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mouse down event handler
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Button)
        {
            case MouseButtons.Middle:
                startingPoint = new Point(e.Location.X - this.Translation.X, e.Location.Y - this.Translation.Y);
                break;
        }

        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mouse move event handler
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mousePosition = Control.MousePosition;

        switch (e.Button)
        {
            case MouseButtons.Middle:
                if (this.Bounds.Contains(e.Location))
                    Translation = new Point(e.Location.X - startingPoint.X, e.Location.Y - startingPoint.Y);
                this.Invalidate();
                break;

            case MouseButtons.Right:
                // Add functionality later
                break;
        }

        base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        float scale;
        float[] translation;

        if (this.Image == null)
            return;

        scale = (float)(this.initialScale * this.ZoomFactor);
        translation = new float[] { (float)(this.Translation.X / scale), ((float)this.Translation.Y / scale) };

        e.Graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);

        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(translation[0], translation[1]);

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.image, new Rectangle(new Point((int)(-this.Width / 2 * scale), (int)(-this.Height / 2 * scale)), new Size(this.image.Width, this.image.Height)));

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

The panning is activated through pressing the wheel. The zooming is done by setting the `zoomFactor` variable. Eventually I would like to do it via the right mouse button, which is why there is the empty `case` block in the `switch` statement in the `OnMouseMove` method.

Comment: If you're using WindowsForms, would suggest a [Piccolo2D](https://code.google.com/p/piccolo2d/) framework. Very performant and easy to use.

Comment: I found a good answer in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814770/zoom-center-of-image/16533358#16533358